# Will creating a new global address book affect or delete the existing default?

Tags: exchange

I am planning on creating a new global address book in our Exchange 2010 as per the code below:

New-GlobalAddresslist "Department1" -ConditionalDepartment "Department1" -IncludedRecipients "AllRecipients"

Will this affect the default global address book in any way or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

That command would add a new global address book and leave the default intact.

Have you looked into just creating a new address list?
Maybe that is what you are looking for?

`New-AddressList Department1 -RecipientFilter {((Department -eq 'Department1'))`

Check out this post on TechNet Address book policies – [Two different GALs based on department attribute](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/akapteina/2012/07/12/address-book-policies-two-different-gals-based-on-department-attribute/).
It describes creating two new global address lists and also setting up address book policy (ABP) to provide different GALs for different groups of people.  I think that post would probably help you out.